# Changing praying locations

Tags: salat

What is the significance of praying in different locations, during any given praying *session* which involves obligatory (*farz*) and recommended (*mustahab/nafil*) prayers?

Different *locations* here also include those which are apart by as small as 6" (roughly speaking).

Reading [here](http://www.ummah.com/forum/showthread.php?232855-Question-on-changing-place-to-pray-the-sunnah-prayer) I found out that this action is derived from the saying of the Prophet(saww) that every place that one prays at shall stand witness to your faith on the day of judgment.

Was anything similar to this practiced by the Prophet(saww)?

From what I have heard is that he was very particular of where he did what and had a rationale for each. And even the pillars of the Nabavi mosque were named in accordance to it.

Answer (score 2):

I've searched about it and found this, this action is derived from the [saying of Moa'weya in Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/141)

> ......because the Messenger of Allah (PBUH) ordered us not to follow up the congregational Salat with any other Salat until we have talked (to some one) or moved from the place."

Of course i am translating the saying , but what he means that we can not pray the *fard* and after we finish we go immediately and pray the *nafil* we should separate those prayers, that's why people usually move,  to differentiate between 2 prayers.

I think you can stay in your place if you talked to the man next to you or something. If the place was crowded though it's better not to move so you don't step in front of a another man praying and it's preferable to pray the "nafil" in your home according to these 2 narrations :

- Zaid bin Thabit (RA) reported:

  > The Prophet (PBUH) said, "O people! perform your (voluntary) Salat (prayers) in your homes because the best Salat of a man is the one he performs at home, except the obligatory Salat."
  >   [[Al-Bukhari and Muslim]](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/138)
- Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:

  > I heard the Messenger of Allah (PBUH) saying: "Do not turn your houses into graveyards. Satan runs away from the house in which Surat Al-Baqarah is recited.
  >   [[Muslim]](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/28)

There is another great idea, you can seperate between 2 prayers by *tasbih*. But I dind't find anything about moving a certain distance.

Comment: is Moa'weya a reliable source for taking religion from him?

Comment: Given that sheikh ebn othaymyn used this narration in his fatwa, i think this is a reliable source .
Moa'weya was also one of the greatest sahaba